# Network drivers for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers

I have an older Dell Inspirion 1720 Laptop (came with XP, upgraded to Vista some time ago..) rather than retire it I thought to try to install Ubuntu 12.04 in order to familiarize myself with Linux/Ubuntu...Install went smoothly, but it [Ubuntu] would not recognize either of the integrated network components (Ethernet or Wireless).

What drivers can I/should I use to get the wireless (DW1395) working?
Where can I download those drivers?
How do I install those drivers?

(Once I am networked I'm guessing (from what I have read) the rest of the drivers I need will probably be pretty easy...)

[*note: I have already tried various google searches, but have not found a working answer*]

Comment: Please open the terminal(ctrl+alt+t) run the commands one line at a time: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`
`lsusb`
`nm-tool`
`sudo iwlist scan`
`iwconfig`
`rfkill list all`
`lsmod` post the output at http://pastebin.com/ then post the link here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Your card is Broadcom based.  Broadcom released an updated Linux wireless driver that supports cards based on the Broadcom 4311, 4312, 4321, and 4322 chipsets, which include the Dell 1490, 1395, 1397, 1505, and 1510 Wireless cards.  The driver can be downloaded [Here](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php)